# Python multiprocessing pool map - Memory issues in Databricks

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing, databricks, pool

I am running a python component in Databricks environment which creates a set of JSON messages and each JSON message is encoded with Avro schema. The encoding was taking longer time (8 minutes for encoding 10K messages which have complex JSON structure) and hence I tried to use multiprocessing with pool map function. The process seems to work fine for the first execution, however for subsequent runs, the performance is degrading and eventually failing with oom error. I am making sure that at the end of execution pool.close() and pool.join() are issued but not sure if it's really freeing up the memory. When I look at Databricks Ganglia UI, it shows that Swap memory and CPU utilization is increasing for each run. I also tried to reduce the no of pools (driver node has 8 cores, so tried with 6 and 4 pools) and also maxtasksperchild=1 but still doesn't help. I am wondering if I'm doing anything wrong. Following is the code which I'm using now. Wondering what is cuasing the issue here. Any pointers / suggestions are appreciated.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing
import json
from avro.io import *
import avro.schema
from avro_json_serializer import AvroJsonSerializer, AvroJsonDeserializer
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def create_json_avro_encoding(row):
  row_dict = row.asDict(True)
  json_data = json.loads(avro_serializer.to_json(row_dict))
  #print(f"JSON created { multiprocessing.current_process().name }")
  return json_data 

avro_schema = avro.schema.SchemaFromJSONData(avro_schema_dict, avro.schema.Names())
avro_serializer = AvroJsonSerializer(avro_schema)
records = df.collect()
pool_cnt = int(multiprocessing.cpu_count()*0.5)
print(f"No of records: {len(records)}")
print(f"starting timestamp {datetime.now().isoformat(sep=' ')}")
with Pool(pool_cnt, maxtasksperchild=1) as pool:
  json_data_ret = pool.map(create_json_avro_encoding, records)
  pool.close()
  pool.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't close the pool before joining. In fact, you shouldn't close the pool at all when using it in a with block, it will close automatically when exiting the with block.

Comment: Thanks Imanol! According to official documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), one must call  close() or terminate() before using join(). Also I removed close and join in code and tested, still I see that the memory is not getting freed-up at the end.

Comment: Yes, you must call close() or terminate() if you use the pool outside a with block, when you launch it inside a with block, when you exit the block it will close automatically. Anyway I don't think that will show your problem. It was just a comment.